# Is it possible to contribute to an ESPP outside the % chosen?

Tags: espp

Just curious if it is possible to add additional money to an ESPP during the period before the purchase occurs.  I started mine withholding a little lower than I think I want now that I see what I may be getting.  Can I add to the account somehow to increase it?  Other than upping the percentage I mean.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you asked your HR rep?